# how to automatically restart the dependent program

Tags: linux, restart, systemd

Now there are two procedures, A rely on B, if B upgrade, A will not restart the service will be abnormal, how to automatically restart A after the B upgrade

Comment: Like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043964/how-to-restart-a-service-if-its-dependent-service-is-restarted